# Python Pound to Kilogram

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help displaying "cannot convert negatives" in tkinter.
I want it to say "cannot convert negatives" when I type in a negative number.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *

def convert():

    P = float(pound.get())
    K = P * 0.453592
    Kilogram.set(str(K))

    input (P)
    if (P) < 0:
        print("cannot convert negitaves") # i need to display this when i run the program 
    else:
        K = P * 0.453592
        print(K)

my_window = Tk()
Kilogram = StringVar()
pound = StringVar()

label_1 = Label(my_window, text="Enter the pound")
label_2 = Label(my_window, text="Kilogram")
display_kilogram_label = Label(my_window, textvariable=Kilogram)
pound_entry = Entry(my_window, textvariable=pound)
convert_button = Button(my_window, text="Convert", command=convert)

label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
pound_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
display_kilogram_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
convert_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't understand the `input(P)`statement. Is this supposed to be the standard input function? If so, then note, that its argument is the prompt and you have to save the result to get, what was input.

Comment: sorry just ignore that bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented out the "input (P)" line, and refactored your convert function a little bit, now it works:

```
def convert():
    P = float(pound.get())

    # input (P)
    if P < 0:
        print("cannot convert negitaves") # i need to display this when i run the program
    else:
        K = P * 0.453592
        Kilogram.set(str(K))
        print(K)
```

Based on your feedback, I changed the convert function to display the error message as well:

```
def convert():
    P = float(pound.get())

    if P < 0:
        Kilogram.set("Cannot convert negatives!")
    else:
        Kilogram.set(str(P * 0.453592))
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply commenting the `input(P)` line is what you need to do to make your program run.

```
from tkinter import *

def convert():

    P = float(pound.get())
    K = P * 0.453592
    Kilogram.set(str(K))

    if (P) < 0:
        print("cannot convert negitaves") # i need to display this when i run the program 
    else:
        K = P * 0.453592
        print(K)

my_window = Tk()
Kilogram = StringVar()
pound = StringVar()

label_1 = Label(my_window, text="Enter the pound")
label_2 = Label(my_window, text="Kilogram")
display_kilogram_label = Label(my_window, textvariable=Kilogram)
pound_entry = Entry(my_window, textvariable=pound)
convert_button = Button(my_window, text="Convert", command=convert)

label_1.grid(row=0, column=0)
pound_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
label_2.grid(row=1, column=0)
display_kilogram_label.grid(row=1, column=1)
convert_button.grid(row=2, column=0)

my_window.mainloop()
```